# Advantages and Disadvantages of using DB2 Remote Load

Tags: database, db2, remote-access

What is the advantages and disadvantages of using [DB2 Remote Load](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0008305.htm) (load using a remote client) over DB2 Direct load (without using this CLIENT option)?
By using DB2 direct load also we can load remotely located DB2 server.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD CLIENT` transfers your data across the network from your client machine to the database server.  Without the `CLIENT` option, the `LOAD` utility has to have the file available on the database server.

By loading across the network you may sacrifice some raw performance, but you have the advantage of not needing to transfer your file to the database server first.